# nsolve constantly throwing ValueError

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy

I'm currently trying to run this block of code.

```
# %% Imports
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy
import scipy as sc

alpha = sy.Symbol('alpha', real=True) 
beta = sy.Symbol('beta', real=True) 
s_0 = sy.Symbol('s_0', real=True) 
s_1 = sy.Symbol('s_1', real=True) 
s_2 = sy.Symbol('s_2', real=True) 
t = sy.Symbol('t', real=True)


#run checks on S(t) whether S(t) > S0 for current iteration
def main():
    # A. Defining equations to constant variables to be called later
    #S(t) > S0, (S(t) + β/α)*S(t) > 0
    MODEL_1_1 = ((beta/alpha) * (1/sy.Abs((s_0 + beta/alpha)/s_0)) * sy.exp(beta*t)) / (1 - (1/sy.Abs((s_0 + beta/alpha)/s_0) * sy.exp(beta*t)))

    #S(t) > S0, (S(t) + β/α)*S(t) < 0
    MODEL_1_2 = -((beta/alpha) * (1/sy.Abs((s_0 + beta/alpha)/s_0)) * sy.exp(beta*t)) / (1 + (1/sy.Abs((s_0 + beta/alpha)/s_0) * sy.exp(beta*t)))

    #S(t) < S0, (S(t) + β/α)*S(t) > 0
    MODEL_1_3 = ((beta/alpha) * (1/sy.Abs((s_0 + beta/alpha)/s_0)) * sy.exp(-sy.Abs(beta)*t)) / (1 - (1/sy.Abs((s_0 + beta/alpha)/s_0) * sy.exp(-sy.Abs(beta)*t)))

    #S(t) < S0, (S(t) + β/α)*S(t) > 0
    MODEL_1_4 = -((beta/alpha) * (1/sy.Abs((s_0 + beta/alpha)/s_0)) * sy.exp(-sy.Abs(beta)*t)) / (1 + (1/sy.Abs((s_0 + beta/alpha)/s_0) * sy.exp(-sy.Abs(beta)*t)))

    #---------------------------------------------------------------
    # B. Initializing values
    stock_price = [25725, 25600, 24600]

    #---------------------------------------------------------------
    # C. Get 2 functions for every t = 1 and t = 2
    ## C.1. processing t1
    if (stock_price[1] > stock_price[0]):
        eq1 = MODEL_1_1.subs([(t,1),(s_0,stock_price[0])]) #(S(t) + β/α)*S(t) > 0
        eq2 = MODEL_1_2.subs([(t,1),(s_0,stock_price[0])]) #(S(t) + β/α)*S(t) < 0
    
    else:
        eq1 = MODEL_1_3.subs([(t,1),(s_0,stock_price[0])]) #(S(t) + β/α)*S(t) > 0
        eq2 = MODEL_1_4.subs([(t,1),(s_0,stock_price[0])]) #(S(t) + β/α)*S(t) < 0
    
    #print(eq1)
    #print(eq2)

    ## C.2. processing t2
    if (stock_price[2] > stock_price[0]):
        eq3 = MODEL_1_1.subs([(t,2),(s_0,stock_price[0])]) #(S(t) + β/α)*S(t) > 0
        eq4 = MODEL_1_2.subs([(t,2),(s_0,stock_price[0])]) #(S(t) + β/α)*S(t) < 0
    
    else:
        eq3 = MODEL_1_3.subs([(t,2),(s_0,stock_price[0])]) #(S(t) + β/α)*S(t) > 0
        eq4 = MODEL_1_4.subs([(t,2),(s_0,stock_price[0])]) #(S(t) + β/α)*S(t) < 0

    #print(eq3)
    #print(eq4)

    #------------------------------------------------
    # D. Run 4 different solution, get 4 sets of possible (α,β) pair
    ## D.1. eq1 vs. eq3  -- (S(1) + β/α)*S(1) > 0, (S(2) + β/α)*S(2) > 0
    print(eq1)
    print(eq3)
    sol1 = sy.solvers.nsolve([sy.Eq(eq1,stock_price[1]), sy.Eq(eq3,stock_price[2])],[alpha,beta],[-1,1])


    print(sol1)
    ## D.2. eq2 vs. eq3  -- (S(1) + β/α)*S(1) < 0, (S(2) + β/α)*S(2) > 0
    ## D.3. eq1 vs. eq4  -- (S(1) + β/α)*S(1) > 0, (S(2) + β/α)*S(2) < 0
    ## D.4. eq2 vs. eq4  -- (S(1) + β/α)*S(1) < 0, (S(2) + β/α)*S(2) < 0 

#check for contradictions against initial condition
#return values that satisfies all condition
#run t = 3 based on the iteration
#repeat
main()
```

However it keeps throwing

> Could not find root within given tolerance. (655317900.776688019361 >
> 2.16840434497100886801e-19) Try another starting point or tweak arguments.

or

> matrix is numerically singular

whenever I try to tweak around the initial starting point.
Could anyone help / suggest alternatives to nsolve for this particular function?

Edit 1:
adding tracebacks

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\SKRIPSI ANDREE\Code\model1.py", line 76, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\SKRIPSI ANDREE\Code\model1.py", line 64, in main
    sol1 = sy.solvers.nsolve([sy.Eq(eq1,stock_price[1]), sy.Eq(eq3,stock_price[2])],[alpha,beta],[-1,1])
  File "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\utilities\decorator.py", line 88, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 2954, in nsolve
    x = findroot(f, x0, J=J, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mpmath\calculus\optimization.py", line 969, in findroot
    for x, error in iterations:
  File "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mpmath\calculus\optimization.py", line 660, in __iter__
    s = self.ctx.lu_solve(Jx, fxn)
  File "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mpmath\matrices\linalg.py", line 226, in lu_solve
    A, p = ctx.LU_decomp(A)
  File "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mpmath\matrices\linalg.py", line 136, in LU_decomp
    raise ZeroDivisionError('matrix is numerically singular')
ZeroDivisionError: matrix is numerically singular
```

Comment: Clean up the imports.  I see `numpy` and `scipy` that you don't use (and shouldn't).  I see a bare `exp`.  Show the traceback if you get an error.

Comment: hi @hpaulj, the full block of code and tracebacks has been added